# jQuery response fail when fetch data using web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I have implemented a web method to fetch a single record.. web method is working correctly but. data not showing in jQuery AJAX

**jQuery & Ajax Code**

```
function GetBillDetail() {
                debugger;
                var ClientId = jQuery('#<%=HiddenFieldCompanyId.ClientID%>').val()
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<%=mstr_WebsitePath%>webservice/ClientSearch.asmx/GetBillDetaill",
                    data: '{ClientId: "' + ClientId + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {// Data Not Getting Here
                        debugger;
                        var billReport = r.d;
                            jQuery('#ClientName').html(billReport.ClientName);
                            jQuery('#CityName').html(billReport.City);
                            jQuery('#ClientAddress').html(billReport.Address);
                            jQuery('#ClientPhoneNo').html(billReport.PhoneNo);
                    },
                    failure: function (r) {
                        alert(r.d);
                    }
                });
            }
```

**Web Method:**

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetBillDetaill(ByVal ClientId As String) As List(Of BillReport)
        Dim billReportList As New List(Of BillReport)
        Dim mrow_Bill As DataRow
        With BillingDetailBOL.getBillCorrectionDetailBOL(ClientId)
            For Each mrow_Bill In .Rows
                Dim billReport As New BillReport()
                billReport.ClientName = mrow_Bill("ClientName").ToString()
                billReport.City = mrow_Bill("LocalityName").ToString()
                billReport.Address = mrow_Bill("Address").ToString()
                billReport.PhoneNo = mrow_Bill("Phone").ToString()
                billReportList.Add(billReport)
            Next
        End With

        Return billReportList
    End Function
```

**BOL Method Call By Web Method**

```
Public Shared Function getBillCorrectionDetailBOL(ByVal ClientId As String) As DataTable
        Try
            _ILog.WriteToLog("", Severity.Information, "BillingDetailBOL.vb", "getBillCorrectionDetailBOL", "Get Client bill Detail", Level.INFO)
            Dim mobj_dset As New DataSet

            Return BillingDetailDAL.GetBillCorrectionDetailDAL(ClientId).Tables(0)
        Catch piEx As PIException
            _ILog.LogException("", Severity.ProcessingError, "BillingDetailBOL.vb", "getBillCorrectionDetailBOL", piEx)
            Throw piEx
        Catch ex As Exception
            _ILog.LogException("", Severity.ProcessingError, "BillingDetailBOL.vb", "getBillCorrectionDetailBOL", ex)
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
```

**DAL method call by BOL**

```
Public Shared Function GetBillCorrectionDetailDAL(ByVal mstr_ClientId As String) As DataSet
        Try
            _ILog.WriteToLog("", Severity.Information, "BillingDetailDAL.vb", "GetBillCorrectionDetailDAL", "Get Client Detail", Level.INFO)
            Dim commandparameters() As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(0) {}
            commandparameters(0) = New SqlParameter("@ClientId", mstr_ClientId)

            Return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Utilities.WebConfiguration.SQLConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GC_GetCompanyDetail", commandparameters)
        Catch piEx As PIException
            _ILog.LogException("", Severity.ProcessingError, "BillingDetailDAL.vb", "GetBillCorrectionDetailDAL", piEx)
            Throw piEx
        Catch ex As Exception
            _ILog.LogException("", Severity.ProcessingError, "BillingDetailDAL.vb", "GetBillCorrectionDetailDAL", ex)
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
```

I am not getting data at `success: function (r)` Anyone know how can i resolve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

> You `WebMethod` should be `static` in case of VB.Net it should be
>   `Shared`

```
Public Shared Function GetBillDetaill(ByVal ClientId As String) As List(Of BillReport)
```

Comment: Hello @Mairaj , i am using ur code but it is giving me 500 error .. not working

Comment: Can u please see your browser console >

Answer (score 0):

Try to return your data in json format string.

Serialize List data it to json and change the return type of a function to a string.

Comment: Hello @Sumit, I have used serialization `Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(billReportList))` but it is not working too

Comment: Curser goes to failure part 'failure: function (r) {
                        alert(r.d);
                    }`

Comment: you are getting any specific error in the alert?also how many records are returned by the function?

Comment: Not getting any specific error. it is giving me `ERROR` in pop up box

Comment: failure : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){} try this function syntax for failure and check values of these three varibles.